# Is it possible to generate more then one report using non-gui mode in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm using jmeter command as below to run using non-Gui functionality

1.
jmeter -n -t D:\EXAMPLE\PerfomanceTest.jmx -l C:\Users\Deva'g\Desktop\reportfile.jtl -r

2.
jmeter -n -t D:\EXAMPLE\PerfomanceTest.jmx -l C:\Users\Deva'g\Desktop\reportfile.csv -r

both commands working fine.

first one will generate Summary report and second will generate .csv report

but i want both this report together in single execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JMeter Plugins like **[JMeterPluginsCMD](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)**

After your running, you could generate your csv using your reportfile.jtl.

For instance, if you need an AggregateReport:

java -jar JMETER_HOME\lib\ext\CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv reportfile.csv --input-jtl reportfile.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport